# How to capitalize the last five letters of the string and make a string as user entered

Tags: python, uppercase

In my python program the user will enter a string.

If the user entered the string less then five letters then it tells the user

> the string is too short!

If the string entered is more then 5 letters then it will make the uppercase the last five letters of the string.

For example:

```
input: "heroiszero"
output: SZERO

expected output: heroiSZERO
```

#### My program

```
myString= input("Enter the string you want:- ")
print("The String you Entered is :- ", myString)
if len(myString) <= 5:
    print("String is too short!")
else:
    print(myString[-5:].upper())
```

What changes should I have change to get my exact output I want?

Answer (score 4):

Last line should be:

```
print(myString[:-5] + myString[-5:].upper())
```

So you take the string as is up to last five characters and use `+`, which is concatenation, with last five characters converted to `upper()`.

Comment: @meena what you were doing was "take the last 5 letters of the string, make them uppercase, and print them". This one says "take the last 5 letters of the string, make them uppercase, then concatenate them to a copy of the original string but without the last 5 letters, then print the result".

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
myString= input("Enter the string you want:- ")
print("The String you Entered is :- ", myString)
if len(myString) <= 5:
    print("String is too short!")
else:
    print(myString[:-5]+myString[-5:].upper())
```

`myString[-5:]` select the last five items, ignore the others, and then `upper()` convert it to uppercase.
You need to print the first part of the string too if you want to display it.

`myString[:-5]` select all the characters of the string but not the last 5.

`myString[:-5] + myString[-5:]` is the same as `myString`.

Answer (score 2):

You are only taking last 5 index and making it upper and printing.

You must include the other characters ie from index 0 to 5th last index.

It can be done with slicing like this..

```
myString= input("Enter the string you want:- ")

print("The String you Entered is :- ", myString)

if len(myString) <= 5:
    print("String is too short!")
else:
    print(myString[:-5] + myString[-5:].upper())
```

## Working

`myString[:-5]` gives the substring from index 0 to 5th last index

`myString[-5:].upper()` takes last 5 characters and make it upper case

`myString[:-5] + myString[-5:].upper()` concatinates both and gives the result as you need

Answer (score 2):

By doing `print(myString[-5:].upper())` you are only printing out the last 5 characters of that string.
To get your desired output you must concatenate that with the remaining, initial part of your string like this

```
print(myString[:-5] + myString[-5:].upper())
```

However, is this **really what you need**? I thought maybe if the string is longer than 5 characters one might want to leave the first characters intact and capitalize all the remaining ones like this

```
print(myString[:5] + myString[5:].upper())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the last 5 chars from the string , save it in a variable, `upper` it and put it back at the end of the string.

```
myString= input("Enter the string you want:- ")
print("The String you Entered is :- ", myString)
if len(myString) <= 5:
    print("String is too short!")
else:
    temp = myString[-5:]  #getting last 5 chars of string
    myString = myString[:-5]  #removing last 5 chars from the string
    temp = temp.upper()  #making the saved 5 chars capital
    myString = myString+temp  #adding the capital 5 chars back to string
print(myString)
```

If you want it to be simpler with the same concept:

```
else:
    temp = myString[-5:].upper()
    myString = myString[:-5] + temp
```

Testing the code:

```
Enter the string you want:- heroiszero
The String you Entered is :-  heroiszero
heroiSZERO
```